# How to filter in a table column contains list in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table column A=['1','2','3'] and I want filter from the table if the filter value is exist in the list.

eg:
`id='1'`
`Models.objects.filter(A=id)`

Comment: `Model.objects.filter(A__in=list_id)` i suppose that A is the column and list_id is what you want to filter.

Comment: No, A is the column and that column contains list of values

Comment: what is the field's name in your model ?

Comment: A is the field name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object = Models.objects.filter(A__contains=id)`

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the name of the model is Foo, in order to find the object with the column A=id, you would do:

```
object = Foo.objects.filter(A=id)
```

This has the same effect as:

```
object = Foo.objects.filter(A__exact=id)
```

Comment: Got the answer, we can use contains
```object = Foo.objects.filter(A__contains=id)```